# Splitting up the rosh chodesh reading when another follows it

Tags: shabbat, chanuka, torah-service, rosh-chodesh-new-month, four-parshiot

[*Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* 684:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=299) says (in my own translation):

> If *rosh chodesh Teves* comes out on *Shabas*, we remove three Torah scrolls, and six people read in the weekly section and one in that of *rosh chodesh*, starting from "*Uv'yom hashabas*"; the *maftir* reads in the third scroll....

[*Mishna B'rura*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=299) comments on "[six read] in the weekly section":

> Likewise if seven, or more than seven, want to read, that's allowed also; the point is that there are no fewer than seven people between [the first two scrolls].

[*Shaar Hatziyun*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=299) adds:

> Likewise, five men can read from the weekly section

— meaning, and two from the second scroll. Presumably the same rules would apply to *Shabas rosh chodesh Adar* and *Shabas rosh chodesh Nisan*.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know of a synagogue in which only five people read from the first scroll? Why do they do this?
2. There are some synagogues that add one *aliya* every week, so eight (plus the *maftir*) read. In weeks with three scrolls, do they add the *aliya* to the first scroll or the second?
3. There are some synagogues that add many *aliyos* every week, stopping as often as every three *p'sukim* (where allowed). Do they also split the second *sefer* between two people?

Comment: Did you look up the pri chadash inside?

Comment: I only mention him because that is the Shaar HaTziyun's quoted source. Haven't had a chance to see him myself. In fact, I didn't even know there was a Peri Chadash on hilchot channukah.

Comment: Link http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3111 (still haven't read)

Answer (score 3):

In response to #1 - I have never seen a Shul that gives only 5 Aliyos from the first Torah, and I would be surprised to hear that there is a Shul that does that.

In response to #2 - My Shul always gives an extra Aliya, and this past week they called up 7 in the first Torah, 1 for the second Torah, and 1 for Parshas HaChodesh.

In summation - The only Sefer which only one Aliya is allowable in is the Sefer Torah of the Maftir which is the third Sefer Torah. Although per the Sha'ar Ha'Tziyun you have mentioned the 7 Aliyos can be given from amongst the first two Torah's, to the best of my knowledge the common Minhag is to give only one Aliya from the second Sefer Torah.

Comment: See my supplemental answer. If I'm inaccurate, please inform me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Gershon's answer, there's probably a good reason as to why only 1 aliyah is given from the 2nd Torah. There are two rules regarding reading aliyot:

1 - At least 3 verses must be read

2 - At least 3 verses must be left to the end of the current parsha

There are two parshiot read from the 2nd (Shabbat / Rosh Hodesh reading). The Shabbat parsha has just two verses. The Rosh Hodesh parsha has five.

While, technically, one could read the Shabbat & 3 verses from the 2nd parsha for the 1st oleh and repeat verse 13 for the 2nd oleh, common (at least Ashkenazi) practice is to avoid repeating read verses for a "regular" (non-maftir) oleh. (Rosh Hodesh weekday is an exception, as there is no other way to break up the aliyot for 4 people.)

See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69202/5275) for specifics about weekday Rosh Hodesh aliyot allocation.

Comment: Maybe if you decided to do this for some reason, you'd read the tamid too, like we do during the week.